# FutureWarning in pandas when filtering on Boolean column

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I matched 2 columns in a DataFrame and yield the result in Boolean value in a new 'bool' column.
First I wrote:

```
df_new = df[[7 for 32 in df if df 39 == 'False']]
```

But it didn't work.

Then I wrote only to match the columns

My code is

```
df['bool'] = (df.iloc[:, 7] == df.iloc[:, 32])
```

The above code matched the columns positioned at 7 and 32 and placed `bool` value at column 39. In this I want to slice the data and choose the rows with a false value.
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB6gX.png)

I wrote:

```
df_filtered = df[df['bool'] == 'False']
```

But I got the Future error as

> [c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:714: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
>     result = getattr(x, name)(y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YnOh.png)

Not sure what wrong I am doing.
I've also tried

```
df[df[39] == 'False']
```

Comment: Could you post small sample data and expected result? `By the way 'False' is string dtype and False is bool`

Comment: I just attached the data set and expected result including what I have tried.

Comment: WoodChopper : Please check the Data Link in question ... added just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the columns directly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 3, 2]})

df['Bool'] = df.a == df.b

>>> df
   a  b   Bool
0  1  1   True
1  2  3  False
2  3  2  False
```

To filter for False values, use the negation flag, i.e. `~`:

```
>>> df[~df.Bool]
   a  b   Bool
1  2  3  False
2  3  2  False
```

Comment: yes, till here I have the result but I need to further slice this data based on False value only.

a  b   bool
1  2  3  False
2  3  2  False

Comment: Alexander -  Thanks for the reply but I din't get the result as mentioned...

My original code is :
 
Delta_check[~Delta_check.bool]

I got
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'method'

Comment: What is the exact name of your column?

Comment: bool is the exact name of my column

Comment: `bool` is a DataFrame method, so you need to use explicit referencing: `df[~df['bool']]`

Comment: Delta_check['bool'] = (Delta_check.iloc[:, 7] == Delta_check.iloc[:, 32])

---------------------------

Delta_check[~Delta_check.['bool']]

_________________________

 File "<ipython-input-50-1b3d5b6c356e>", line 1
    Delta_check[~Delta_check.['bool']]
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You have an extra period that needs to be removed.  `Delta_check[~Delta_check.['bool']] ` -> `Delta_check[~Delta_check['bool']] `

Comment: Was stuck on this for last 2 days,,,, Thankyou,,

Comment: Glad to help.  Would you mind ticking the check mark indicating that this solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your situation, I get the "FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a boolean array index" when I use those code as below:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> test=np.array([1,2,3])
>>> test3=test[[False,True,False]]
__main__:1: FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a boolean array index
>>> test3=test[np.array([False,True,False])]
>>> test3
array([2])
>>>
```

I think these are some relations between the two "FutureWarning", I hope my situation can help you.